# How does EOS integrate WASM?

Tags: wasm

WASM (Web Assembly) is relatively new. How does EOS make use of WASM? And are there other blockchains working with WASM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart contract in EOS are developed in C++, then compiled into wasm code using `eosiocpp` (or `eosio-cpp`) and uploaded to the blockchain using `cleos set contract`. Why wasm? Read [this post](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/why-wasm-instead-of-custom-virtual-machine), basically for speed performances. Ethereum also seems to want to use wasm, there is a project called [ewasm](https://github.com/ewasm/design).

Comment: Aside from ethereum. What other blockchains are taking this approach?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ ontology, polkadot, dfinity, hyperledger, probably more